# WPF retrieve leap info from different class

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, leap-motion

The quick version of my problem is that WPF does not accept variables from a different thread.

```
error message: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
```

Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Because I subscribe to the leap frame event, I can't find a work around for the second thread. Is there some way in the following code to place frame info in a textbox?

```
// MainWindow
LeapReader reader = new LeapReader();
public MainWindow()
{
    reader.Frame += reader_Frame;
}

void reader_Frame(string coordinate)
{
    //textbox which will output coordinates of the hand
    txtCoord.Text = coord;
}


// LeapReader
string _coordinates = "";
public delegate void StringEvent(string coord);
public event StringEvent Frame;

void SomeRetrievalMethod(Frame frame)
{
    _coordinates = Cursor.Position.ToString();
    Frame.Invoke(_coordinates);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatch it back to the `TextBox's Dispatcher`. It would be better if you just use bindings and let `WPF` handle dispatching between threads for you.

```
void reader_Frame(string coordinate)
{
    //textbox which will output coordinates of the hand
    txtCoord.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => txtCoord.Text = coord));
}
```

Comment: Here's a good resource to help understand what the hell the Dispatcher is. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Comment: @MikeEason That article is too old. If you are using .NET 4.5 >. It's better to use `async/await` with TPL than `BackgroundWorkers`. And use `Rx` for a better responsive app